# Navigate to screen from push notification flutter_local_notification package

Tags: flutter, push-notification, flutter-local-notification

I am using the flutter_local_notification package to handle notifications from a third party server (not firebase cloud messaging). Because I am using firebase but not firebase messaging, I am using the onSelectNotification function of the flutter-local_notification package.

This is the function that I pass to onSelectNotification:

```
static _selectNotification(String payload, StreamChatClient client, RemoteMessage message) {
    debugPrint('notification payload: $payload');

    if(payload.contains('livestream')) {
      Utils.db.getLiveRoom(payload.split(":")[1]).then((liveRoom) {
        Navigator.push(
          NavigationService.navigatorKey.currentContext!,
          MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (context) => LiveRoomChat(liveRoom: liveRoom)),
        );
      });
    }
    else {
      List<String> ids = message.data['channel_id'].toString().split('_');
      String receiverId = '';
      if(ids[0] == Utils.user?.uid) {
        receiverId = ids[1];
      }
      else {
        receiverId = ids[0];
      }

      Navigator.push(
        NavigationService.navigatorKey.currentContext!,
        MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (context) => MessageApi(
            sourceType: Utils.friends.containsKey(receiverId) ? SourceType.friends : SourceType.justMet,
            receiverId: receiverId,
            channelId: payload.split(":")[1],
            streamToken: Utils.user?.streamToken ?? '',
            client: client
        )),
      );
    }
  }
```

I have a global navigator key which I have defined in a NavigationService class, and I also assign this navigator key in the main.dart. **This notification handling above works for ios but it does not work for android because NavigationService.navigatorKey.currentContext is always null on android.** Does anyone know why this is the case on android, and what is the way to handle it?

Comment: Why don't you use `context` directly instead of `NavigationService.navigatorKey.currentContext` ?

Comment: Which version of `flutter_local_notifications` are you using?

Comment: Could you post the code where you handle the NavigationService.navigatorKey?

Comment: @CenkYAGMUR That's what I explained in the question. I do that and it works for ios but for android, it returns null

Comment: @abichinger I am using version ^9.9.1

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to run your code inside that?

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
     _selectNotification();
    });
  }
```

if you are not running your code in initstate try sending buildcontext to your function

```
static _selectNotification(BuildContext context, String payload, StreamChatClient client, RemoteMessage message) {}
```

Comment: I can't put _selectNotification in an initState because the code lives inside a singleton class and not a stateful widget. I also cannot pass the context to the function because the _selectNotification function is being called by a top-level function in another stateful widget. That is, the function calling it does not have access to the build context

Answer (score 0):

I will share my project work flow it may help you.

Initialized FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin instance as global variable(above main() method).

Defined a class GlobalVariable in main.dart

passing GlobalVariable.navState to parameter nagavigatorKey of MaterialApp in MyApp class.

in initState method of _MyAppState, initialized the flutterLocalNotificationPlugin.

in onSelectNotification method, made Navigation call within SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback.

Defined route of page in routes.dart file.

Please check the code. You may find anything useful.

```
    import ....

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
            FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
        runApp(MyApp());
    }


  onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
            
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                GlobalVariable.navState.currentState.pushNamed(
                    give routeName,
                    arguments: givearguments);
              });    
     
  }


    class GlobalVariable {
       static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navState = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
    }

    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          navigatorKey: GlobalVariable.navState, //this is must
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Home',
          home: ScreenOne(),
          routes: routes,
        );
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        var initializationSettingsAndroid =
            new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    
        var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
            android: initializationSettingsAndroid);
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
            onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
        registerNotification();
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
        super. Dispose();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mention permission inside your android manifest file?

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

you will find their manifest file for example here

[Example manifest file link](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/master/flutter_local_notifications/example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: Yes I have that permission already